# JSF jumping to anchor right away

Tags: jsf, navigation, scroll, anchor

When a JSF commandLink is clicked, the scrollposition of the new page will be 0 - which is fine.

I noticed a strange behaviour with one of my jsf pages - but its acuallty quite hard to explain:
Clicking on a link in order to navigate "somewhere" usually freezes the page and when the new response is received, you'll end up on another page and the scrollposition gets reseted. This is fine.

In that particular case the "current" view is immediately scrolling to the top, once a commandlink is clicked, and THEN forwards to the desired navigation outcome.

Its like clicking on a plain link, that has just its anchor set to the top. `<a href='#'>`

What could be a possible reason for this? It feels very strange, if the page scrolls up the second you click on a link.

All pages have basically the same usage of commandlinks within datatables. No other page encounters that problems. The Controllers are different - but since the scrolling up is done within milliseconds, I dont think, that this is a server-side issue.

I noticed that jsf appends the `#` to all links, that are generated.

so, when I click on the link, I can see the url changing to `.../page.xhtml#` for a split second (the split second, the page scrolls up), and then getting re-jsft like `.../page.xhtml?cid=4`

edit:
for all my pages, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('openTaskTable:0:j_idt64'),{'openTaskTable:0:j_idt64:j_idt65':'openTaskTable:0:j_idt64:j_idt65'},'');return false">SVA</a>
```

However on that said page the `return false;` at the end is missing... which then makes the link behave like an anchor...

edit2:
The working-as-expected-links are generated, using `<h:commandLink>` - the ones that are making the page scroll up, are `<p:commandLink>`s (Primefaces). Indeed, replacing it, solves the issue, but still wonder what's different for the primefaces link.

edit3: Example

working as expected:

```
<h:form style="display:inline;">
    <h:commandLink
         action="#{processManagementController.unpinProcess(process)}">
   <h:graphicImage
    style="display:inline-block; height:16px; width:16px;"
    value="/resources/img/pinned.png"
    title="Click to unpin this process" />
</h:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

causes immediate scrolling:

```
<h:form style="display:inline;">
    <p:commandLink ajax="false"
         action="#{processManagementController.unpinProcess(process)}">
   <h:graphicImage
    style="display:inline-block; height:16px; width:16px;"
    value="/resources/img/pinned.png"
    title="Click to unpin this process" />
</p:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: It would be better for us if you add a sample of your `<h:commandLink>` usage.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Example added.

Comment: `<h:commandLink>` doesn't have `ajax` attribute. Are you sure this is a real sample of your code?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, just forgot to remove that, because it was a `p:commandLink` (primefaces) prior. As stated in edit 2: using `h` works, `p` causes that jumps. (`h`s output contains the `return false`, `p`s not - bug or feature? :P )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not scrolled to top due to `href="#"`, but because of the synchronous postback (which results in a complete reload of the page!). The both examples in your "edit3" still scrolls to top for me.

Nest `<f:ajax>` in the `<h:commandLink>`, or set `ajax="true"` on the `<p:commandLink>` to make it an asynchronous postback and thus get them to behave as intented.

Comment: Yes they both still scroll up. That's what i called "hard" to explain: It is okay, that this happens, but the primefaces link causes the scrolling like 4ms after clicking a link. the h-commandlink does not change the scroll-position UNTIL the actual response is generated.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem when using the code snippet in your "edit 3". Both links scroll up. Once I make them asynchronous, both links do not scroll up. In all the 3 major browsers with Mojarra 2.1.17 and PrimeFaces 3.5.